# Best IDE for debugging and Code Completion in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP framework. Does anybody have any experience with a free IDE for Uuntu which can perform code completion and most importantly ability to debug CakePHP code?

Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any accepted answers would be even more greatly appreciated

Answer (score 12):

I would use Netbeans, and I mean, I do use Netbeans. It can intelligently work across inherited classes so works very well against CakePHP.

http://netbeans.org/

> #### Updated:
>
> In addition, now [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) IDE has got a [plugin for CakePHP](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44579/php-cakephp-framework)

Comment: Not too sure on the debugging side. For PHP debug I connect Netbeans to XDebug on my server, and also run CakePHP DebugKit http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-debugkit

Answer (score 3):

[Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) is the best one in my opinion. I have used PhpStorm, Komodo, Aptana Studio 3, Notepad++ and others. All are good IDEs. But [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) is giving me auto complete for CakePHP and other features too. Try it out. You will like it.

Answer (score 1):

See http://mark-story.com/posts/view/code-completion-for-cakephp-in-eclipse

Netbeans works well for PHP in general, you will get full code completion in Controllers, but couldn't get proper completion in Views to work.
Same in Eclipse, however no code formatting for PHP is pretty n00by.

Debugging PHP generally sucks, I mostly use `$this-log()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try [Codelobster PHP Edition](http://www.codelobster.com)

It has free debugger and special plug-in for CakePHP autocompletion.